# cookies not being saved in the browser despite their presence in the network tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, vercel

I recently deployed my backend (written in Express) and frontend apps  to the vercel. Everything works alright except cookies that are being sent from the server. I can see in a **Network** tab that as a response to the login request i receive:

```
set-cookie: refreshToken=<token>; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 24 Jan 2023 21:02:31 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
```

The problem is that despite that response my cookies are not being saved in the **Application** tab. **This problem does not occur on localhost.**

What can cause this issue?

**Backend (Express.js)**:

**cors package config**:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://my-deployed-frontend-app.vercel.app",
  })
);
```

**cookies sent as a response for login request**:

```
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {
   expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
   secure: true,
   // httpOnly: true,
   sameSite: "none",
 });
```

**vercel.json config file**:

```
 {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Frontend (TS React + Axios)**:

**Axios config:**

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://my-deployed-app-backend.vercel.app/api",
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

**Login request**:

```
 const login = async (args: LoginArgs) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/login", {
        username: args.username,
        password: args.password,
      });

      const { data } = response;
      const { token } = data;

      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", "Bearer " + token);

      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
```

**EDIT:** I can see that the cookies are being set in the deployed backend but not in the deployed frontend. Can it be caused by different domains since when i was working on localhost the domain was just localhost but with different port? If its the case, there is a problem because i cannot set same domain for 2 projects (backend, frontend) in vercel. Is there a workaround?

Comment: How are you sending that login request?

Comment: I updated the post with Frontend part

Comment: You mean the cookie is set on the response header when you authenticate the first time, but when you try to login again the cookie is not attach to the request header ?

Comment: Yes, there is cookie only in the response headers but not in request headers like it was in localhost.
I can also see that on my deployed backend there is cookie saved by a browser but not on the deployed frontend. Can it be caused by different domains since when i was working on localhost the domain was just localhost but with different port?